# maps, php, sql. Inserção de coordenadas na base de dados e reaver map (google) com essas coordenadas

Tags: php, javascript, sql, google-maps

Tenho um mapa dinâmico (pelo menos gostaria que fosse), queria que dependesse do user, este introduzia as coordenadas (com base num form) que quisesse e eram introduzidas na base de dados... até aí tudo bem. Mas depois como introduzia essas coordenadas dentro da formatação do google maps, no parametro 'center'?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

                function init() {

                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 14,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT(COOR1), LONG(COORD2)),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        streetViewControl: false,
                        scrollwheel: false,
                        panControl: false,
     };



    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');


                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
            }
```

Comment: Ta, se eu entendi direito, você já está salvando corretamente as cordenadas, só falta centralizar o mapa com elas, é isso mesmo ??

Comment: é isso, acho que acabei de resolver o problema... O problema aqui era inserir coordenadas armazenadas na DB e reave-las por php, tinham de ser inseridas dentro de javascript (no parametro 'center' no map). Foi fácil, acho que estava só com preguiça mental. vou postar a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui desta maneira:

```
<?php
$lat = '38.689527';
$long = '-9.351307';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init);
    function init() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(' .$lat. ', ' .$long. '),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            panControl: false,
        };
        var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
    }

</script>';
```